# Intel Pin call a function in the application program

Tags: c++, c, intel-pin

I am using the Intel Pin tool to do some analysis on my application program. I have an instrumentation routine and a signal handler that does some analysis in the application program and then based on some condition makes a call to a function in the application program to update some value.

My application program is written in C which is as follows-

```
int pin_flag; //global variable in the C program

void access_from_pin()
{
    pin_flag = 1;
}

void Check() //empty function in C
{
}

int main()
{
    while(!pin_flag)
    {
        Check();
    }
    printf("Pin has changed the flag");
}
```

My Pintool in C++ is as follows-

```
VOID check_routine(THREADID tid, ADDRINT ret)
{
    ADDRINT *addr = ; //hardcode address of the function access_from_pin
    ((void(*)(void))addr)();
}

VOID Image(IMG img, VOID *v)
{
    RTN check_call = RTN_FindByName(img, "Check");
    if (RTN_Valid(check_call))
    {
        RTN_Open(check_call);

        RTN_InsertCall(check_call, IPOINT_AFTER, (AFUNPTR)check_routine,IARG_THREAD_ID,IARG_END);

        RTN_Close(check_call);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PIN_InitSymbols();

    if (PIN_Init(argc, argv)) 
            return Usage();

    /* Image Instrumentation function*/
    IMG_AddInstrumentFunction(Image, 0);

    PIN_StartProgram();    
    return 0;
}
```

When I run my pintool with the application program as the C program, I get a segmentation fault. Is the Image routine the correct way to check a call for a particular function? Also can I directly access a function from the application program using its address? I get the address of the function through some other means, and it is valid so that is not the problem. Since Pin modifies the code at runtime and this pintool simply modifies the flow of the instructions and on a certain condition I should be able to jump to a valid address. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pin, so this is just a stab in the dark: Check the RTN_xxx and other system like functions PIN_xxx IMG_xxx functions for return code failures. Likely if one of these are failing then things cannot proceed  without problems.

Comment: @tambre the application program is in C and the pintool is in C++

Answer (score 1):

You must use PIN_CallApplicationFunction API to call a function in the application in a way that would actually work.